# Is division by zero a not well-formed expression(formula)?

Tags: logic

Suppose I have the following definition: "$a^{-1}$ is such a real number that $a^{-1}\cdot a = 1$". Will the folowing expression be well-formed ?
$$1\cdot 0^{-1} = 2$$ It seems to me that we cannot reason about truth of the following expression so it is not. If it is well-formed, what is the exact technical mistake about the expression above ? And if it is not well-formed, what is the reason by that ?
Note: I am not trying to argue that division by zero must be accepted, but rather trying to understand rigorous explaining of its "imposibility".
And also, I know that we can prove that there exists no real number $x$ such that:$x\cdot0=1$. So you do not need to prove it to me, if you need it in the answer.
EDIT: I`m talking about real numbers only.

Comment: Division by zero is possible in the extended complex plane.

Comment: @Shaun I`m talking about real numbers only. I will specify that in the question.

Comment: well-formed is relative to a language with precise syntactical rules, i.e. a formal language. Example of ill-formed (form formal arithmetic) : $3+=0$

Comment: If we adopt the usual approach of [field axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)#Classic_definition), we have : "Multiplicative inverses: for every $a ≠ 0$, there exists an element denoted by $a^{−1}$." If so, the expression $0^{−1}$ is *meaningless*.

Comment: It's possible in the extended real line too.

Comment: @Shaun I'm talking about non-extended real line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a well-formed formula to even make sense, you need to first specify the language. I'll assume that you mean the language of fields: $0,1$ are constant symbols, $+,\cdot$ are the binary function symbols.

Now we add another symbol $\cdot^{-1}$, and we wish to postulate that it denotes the multiplicative inverse. And therein lies the rub.

You want to treat this as a function symbol, but a function symbol needs to be defined on the whole domain of the structure. So $0^{-1}$ needs to be specified. We can say that $0^{-1}=0$, and in the added axioms that postulate that $a\cdot a^{-1}=1$, require that $a\neq 0$. This way, we generally get to ignore the value of $0^{-1}$ for all practical purposes.

Another way of doing this, is to take $\cdot^{-1}$ as a binary *relation* symbol, and postulate that it defines a function on the non-zero reals. This has the obvious drawback of not being a function symbol, meaning you cannot use it in terms, but you can work around this, of course, by saying that there exists some $z$ which satisfies the $\cdot^{-1}$ with $a$ (namely, $z=a^{-1}$) and then treat $z$ as $a^{-1}$ for all practical purposes of your formula.

---

In either case, the problem in your question comes from not paying enough attention to the details of what it means to be a well-formed formula, in the sense of not paying attention to the specifics of the language and its interaction with the pre-existing structure.

Comment: Do we need to know that number with some properties exists for treating it in the equation ?

Comment: Yes, that is part of the axioms of a field.

Comment: Oh, then that explains a lot to me.

Comment: Actually, I haven't found something like this in field axioms.

Comment: Have you been looking at any books that give an axiomatic definition for "field"?

Comment: OK,then I will look for the axiomatic definition, thanks.